# JQUery Animation2

Tags: jquery, animation

```
    $("#element1").animate({left:"100%",marginLeft:"0px"}, 2000);


    $('#element2').animate({backgroundPosition: '(-625px -30px)'}, 20000);
```

What does the first element is doing? I abit confused with this left and marginleft thing?
Left an marginLeft both reference the left edge. marginLeft:0px means sticking toward the left edge. I am quite undersatnd left:100% .

And the second element is animated to offscreen?  my understanding is the very top left top is (0px, 0px)  moving right and down would increase positive px.  so anything negative.
can I understand x=-625px   and y=-3px?

Answer (score 1):

The first element moves left (if it has an absolute positioning, and change (?) its margin to 0), and for the second element, it's its background which is moving, that doesn't make it offscreen.

Both will be animated depending on their original state.